# Multiple Get Requests Within One Function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send JSON from two urls to one webpage(one that I am creating). It works perfectly when I send one request, but as soon as I add another request it sends an error saying "Can't set headers after they are sent:.

```
app.get("/service", function(req, res) {
    request("http://example.com", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("example.ejs", { data: data });
        }
    })

    request("http://123.com", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("example.ejs", { data: data });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're performing two requests in sequence, but you're attempting to render between requests, too. This is why you're getting the "headers already sent" notice.

What you'll probably need to do, in your case, is make one request, then if it's successful (in your if block, in this case), make the second request... and _then_ render everything you need all at once.

This approach uses nested callbacks, which can become difficult to read after awhile. Consider using the Promise pattern to simplify things, if you can.

Comment: or, send them both like you are now, and when both are complete, combine them into one response and send.

Comment: @Connor Thank you for your response, I tried doing this but whatever function is posted second overrides the first one. I'm trying to find away to get the JSON from both websites to display together.

Comment: @KevinB How would I combine them into one response?

Comment: Depends on the result you want. In this case you seem to be needing two different views, which is a bit weird.

Comment: @KevinB I just noticed I typed it incorrectly and edited... Might make more sense to you now

Comment: well, no, i was referring to you rendering two different views. abc.ejs and 123.ejs. You have two sets of data that according to your sample code have nothing to do with each other. so... how you combine them will depend on how they relate to each other. Might be as simple as concatenating one with the other.

Comment: @KevinB Accidentally changed the wrong thing. You were correct, I only want to send it to one view

Comment: Ah, then you'd simply need to combine the two sets of data into one, and then call render only once, once both requests are complete.

Comment: @KevinB Is it bad that I don't know how to do that?

Comment: well, it depends on what the data is. if it's a string, you concatenate just like other strings, if its an array, you array.concat, if its an object, you extend, etc

Comment: Didn't work, but I'll keep trying and keep you updated. thank you!

Comment: @Salt Why do you make two post with same question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601621/combine-get-requests-in-nodejs/

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Just because it's the same code doesn't mean it's the same question....................

Comment: They were same code, different question, but... to answer one, you also had to answer the other, in both cases, making them dupes.  If you simplified them both to each focus on one of the two problems they wouldn't have been dupes.

Comment: @KevinB Not true at all, combining them into one JSON array and using multiple get requests to send two different JSON Arrays are two totally different methods...

Comment: Right, but... if you fix using 
multiple get requests, it still doesn't fix your problem, because the error will still be happening because you'd still have two res.render. The real problem is you're using res.render() twice, which has little to do with sending multiple requests.

Comment: @KevinB It actually has all to do with sending multiple requests... There are TWO (one or more is multiple) websites, which you need to request their JSON from................

Comment: Right, and that's not something you can't remove, and therefore isn't a problem. the problem is still you're using res.render twice. you can solve it using any method that combines the results of two asynchronous actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because you render `example.ejs` twice this not allowed. I will show you two ways to achieve your goal without any error.

1) This way is a best practice.

```
// Install request-promise package first using this command below:
npm install request-promise;

// then replace your code with this one below: 

app.get("/service", function(req, res) {

    var request = require('request-promise');

    var data1;

    request("http://example.com")
    .then(function(data) {
        data1 = JSON.parse(data);

        return request("http://123.com");
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        data2 = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('data1', data1, 'data2', data2);

        res.render("example.ejs", { data1: data1, data2: data2 });
    });

});
```

and second way:

2) This way is bad practice avoid to use callback inside callback, but anyway it works.

```
app.get("/service", function(req, res) {

    request("http://example.com", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data1 = JSON.parse(body);

            request("http://123.com", function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var data2 = JSON.parse(body);
                    console.log('data1', data1, 'data2', data2);

                    res.render("example.ejs", { data1: data1, data2: data2 });
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Summary: I suggest you to use 1 way, read this article about promises:
https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/ and write clean code. I simply explain that promises are tool to avoid callback inside callback.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great